# Add code to header based on category for specific posts?

Tags: categories, customization, blog

[image]

Hello all! I'm trying to add as you'll see in the image attached a small huffington post icon and accompanying text to some posts on my blog. I'd like to set up a category "Huffington Post" and when this category was checked for a new post, it would add the "As Published on.." text and Huff Post icon to the post. I don't want this code on every post just the posts that are denoted by this category. Any help is much appreciated!
Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) in the codex. You would either insert this into your theme within the post loop or create a function in `functions.php` that'll insert the image and text you want when a post from that category is displayed on screen.

Here's a test bit of code I put together that works well in the Twenty Fourteen theme. I put it inside the loop in `content.php` as a quick test.

```
if (in_category(1)) { 
    the_title();
    echo "<p style='font-size:80px'>Category 1 Test</p>";
}
```